# Wordpress - Replace original image size with specified

Tags: wordpress, image, resize, rescale

I am currently trying to replace the original size of any image upload to my WordPress media gallery. I have tested 2 plugins (imsanity, resize image after upload) stating to resize the image, as well as various validated php scripts. Nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the new sizes in `settings/medias` form the WordPress admin then to use [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin.

Hope it will help.